# is there support for a home battery on google home. Enable triggers for starting devices when home battery is full

Tags: battery, google-home

i want to develop a smart home application linking my home battery (coupled to solar panels) to Google Home. This would allow for efficient use of the solar energy by activating certain devices or routines when the home battery is full and energy will start flowing back to the power grid.

Does such a device type exist or how to create it and are routine triggers possible based on the devices charging level?

thanks